# jqgrid colnames (href) links in the header

Tags: jqgrid

Please tell me how you can make a column name in jqgrid working reference.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#table").jqGrid({
            url: 'test.php',
        imgpath: 'css/flick/images',
            datatype: 'json',
        height: 'auto',
        width: 1050,
        sortname: 'id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['id', '<a href="index.php" >INDEX LINK</a>', 'notes'],
            colModel: [{name:'id', index:'id', width:320, align:'left', sortable:false, search:false},
                        {name:'data', index:'data', width:320, align:'left', sortable:false, search:false},
                        {name:'notes', index:'notes', width:320, align:'left', sortable:false, search:false}],
        rowNum: 50,
        viewrecords: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        hidegrid: false,
        loadonce: true
    });
});
```

The tooltip shows that the reference is to move on but it does not come out – not active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right solution, but this works,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#th_id").click(function() {
      window.open('http://www.google.com');
    });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3DUC/55/). Hope this helps.